# Windows Service Start Error: "The Netlogon service does not need to run in this configuration"

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-services

I'm facing an issue while trying to run a Windows Service using a specific user account (not LocalSystem, LocalService or LocalService).

The service creation is successful with the following PowerShell script:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential

$serviceParams = @{
    Name            = "..."
    BinaryPathName  = "..."
    Credential      = $credentials
    Description     = "..."
    DisplayName     = "..."
    StartupType     = "Automatic"
}

New-Service @serviceParams
```

However, when I'm trying to start the service, it throws an error: **"The dependency service or group failed to start."**

I've checked the error description in Event Viewer: **"This computer is configured as a member of a workgroup, not as a member of a domain. The Netlogon service does not need to run in this configuration".**

I've already took the following steps:

Checked Netlogon service status:

- Status: ""
- Startup type: "Manual"

Checked service dependencies in my service (Properties -> Dependencies): found no dependencies listed.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: What is the service supposed to do?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The service itself is a background long-running ASP.NET application, the main goal of which is to communicate with some external APIs. I also have a WPF application that communicates with this ASP.NET-based service over HTTP.

Comment: And you're not manually invoking any ServiceController related stuff in `ServiceBase.OnStart()`? No runtime dependencies on Active Directory / `System.DirectoryServices.*`?

Comment: And the logon account (the one you capture credentials for) is a local user account on the machine, not a domain account? Then I'm afraid I'm out of good ideas :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen No, there is no ServiceController related code or dependencies on Active Directory. 
By the way, this is how the Windows Service is configured:

`WebApplicationOptions options = new WebApplicationOptions
    {
        Args = args,
        ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default,
    };

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);

builder.Host.UseWindowsService();` (sorry for formatting..)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm using the 'whoami' one: azuread\myname..

Comment: That'd explain. To my best knowledge no current version of Windows supports azuread identities as service logon account. You need to create and assign a _local_ user account for that (make sure you [grant it the requisite access rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/granting-access-rights-to-the-service-logon-account))

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you very much for you time! I'll research the link you mentioned and come back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/event-id-3095/d6e41ae9-1e51-461b-9f41-34af8821da36

This is not an error, its telling you that if you're not planning to join a domain, you can change the `Netlogon` service from automatic to manual and then stop it.

The link above has instructions on how to do this, try this and let me know if this helps.